# Nestjs Swagger - Publishing different API docs on separate routes

Tags: swagger, nestjs, nestjs-swagger

I am building an app that has public API and internal one. I would like to publish docs for these to different routes. I thought this would be accomplished by adding only certain tags to document (`addTag`) but after further reading and experiments it does not do the job.

The docs always contain everything, all documented endpoints from all modules.

Is this even possible? If so, how?

I don't believe code is necessary but FWIW:

```js
const pubOptions = new DocumentBuilder()
    .setTitle('Pub API Docs')
    .setDescription('Blah blah API documentation')
    .setVersion(p.version)
    .addBearerAuth()
    .addTag('public-app')
    .build();
const document = SwaggerModule.createDocument(app, pubOptions);
SwaggerModule.setup('public-api', app, document);

const internalOptions = new DocumentBuilder()
    .setTitle('Internal API Docs')
    .setDescription('Blah blah API documentation')
    .setVersion(p.version)
    .addBearerAuth()
    .addTag('internal')
    .build();
const iDocument = SwaggerModule.createDocument(app, internalOptions);
SwaggerModule.setup('internal-api', app, iDocument);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to tell the `SwaggerModule.createDocument` function what modules to include in the swagger that is to be composed. [Here are the related docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/openapi/other-features#multiple-specifications). As a third parameter, you can pass in an object with an `include` property that contains an array of modules. These modules are the ones related to the swagger document that is about to be built.

Comment: According to this [PR](https://github.com/nestjs/swagger/pull/1289) , the `exclude` option is going to be added as a complement